# Is it possible for a fragment to extend a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm new to mobile development and I'm not sure if this can work. I have a fragment with a Recycled View that displays content. The thing is other fragments also use a Recycler View with the same design. Is it possible to extend that fragment and then reuse everything in it by just changing the Text Views and Images ?

Fragment code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Json;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;
using Homecheck.Adapters;
using Homecheck.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Homecheck.Fragments {
    public class SmokeSensor : Fragment {
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        private List<ItemData> itemData;
        private ISharedPreferences pref;
        private SessionManager session;
        private DeviceModel deviceModel;
        private string cookie;
        private const string URL_SMOKE_DATA = "http://10.1.1.20/appapi/getsmokedata";

        public async override void OnStart() {
            base.OnStart();

            session = new SessionManager();
            pref = Activity.GetSharedPreferences("UserSession", FileCreationMode.Private);
            cookie = pref.GetString("PHPSESSID", string.Empty);
            var jsonFetcher = new JsonFetcher();
            JsonValue jsonDashboard = await jsonFetcher.FetchJsonAsync(URL_SMOKE_DATA, null, null, cookie);
            deviceModel = new DeviceModel();
            deviceModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceModel>(jsonDashboard);

            AddSmokeData();

            adapter = new ViewAdapter(itemData);

            new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() => {
                Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
                    recyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);
                });
            })).Start();
        }

        public void AddSmokeData() {
            itemData = new List<ItemData>();

            foreach (SensorData sensorData in deviceModel.SensorData) {
                if (sensorData.Value == "1") {
                    itemData.Add(new ItemData() {
                        title = GetString(Resource.String.smoke_detected_text),
                        date = sensorData.Timestamp,
                        image = Resource.Drawable.smoke_red,
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SmokeSensor, container, false);
            recyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.smoke_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
            layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.Vertical);

            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.SetItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.AddItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration(20));

            return view;
        }

        public class SpaceItemDecoration : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
            private int space;

            public SpaceItemDecoration(int space) {
                this.space = space;
            }

            public override void GetItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
                outRect.Left = space;
                outRect.Right = space;
                outRect.Bottom = space;

                if (parent.GetChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
                    outRect.Top = space;
                }
            }
        }

        public class ViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter {
            private List<ItemData> itemData;
            private TextView titleText;
            private TextView dateText;
            private ImageView imageId;

            public ViewAdapter(List<ItemData> itemData) {
                this.itemData = itemData;
            }

            public class ItemView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                public View mainView { get; set; }

                public TextView title { get; set; }

                public TextView date { get; set; }

                public ImageView image { get; set; }

                public ItemView(View view) : base(view) {
                    mainView = view;
                }
            }

            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.SmokeSensorItems, null);

                titleText = itemLayoutView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_title);
                dateText = itemLayoutView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_date);
                imageId = itemLayoutView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.item_icon);

                var viewHolder = new ItemView(itemLayoutView) { title = titleText, date = dateText, image = imageId };

                return viewHolder;
            }

            public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
                ItemView itemHolder = viewHolder as ItemView;

                itemHolder.title.Text = itemData[position].title;
                itemHolder.date.Text = itemData[position].date;
                itemHolder.image.SetImageResource(itemData[position].image);
            }

            public override int ItemCount {
                get { return itemData.Count; }
            }
        }

        public class ItemData {
            public string title { get; set; }

            public string date { get; set; }

            public int image { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bad idea, I'll just use one fragment that will show different info, depending on what it gets.

Comment: if you're just using one fragment, consider just using an activity ;)

Comment: No, I'm using multiple fragments, doing different things. But one fragment will display data, depending on what sensor is given.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed this answer, you can extend fragments. I've never seen it done before, but i've just had a play and it works fine. I just think i've never had a case where it makes sense to extend the whole fragment, I tend to just think if something has utility across more than one class, i've put it in another class.

Jame Gosling (head guy who made java) said to not use inheritance as a means to achieve code re-use.

more here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html